# Why do regions expand when moving from Designer to Code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

With Visual Studio 2019, I've noticed lately that whenever I go from the Designer view to Code view, all of my Regions get expanded. It's really frustrating because it moves me away from the spot I was just coding at. Does anyone know if this is a setting I'm missing or if something else is going on?

Comment: Could you provide more details about 'all of my Regions get expanded' ?

Comment: @XingyuZhao a region is an are of code surrounded by #Region #End Region. This is not executable code. It is just a navigation convenience that is collapsible so you can concentrate on one area of code at a time.